# Render directx onto MAUI control

Tags: directx, maui, directx-11

i have dx11 renderer (via SharpDX) doing off-screen rendering onto texture that is a shared resource with dx9. WPF app (that uses this renderer) takes dx9 texture and outputs it on Image control. I want to try to migrate project to MAUI to make it cross-platform (as only WPF constraints it to windows at the moment, as i understand), but due to MAUI being relatively new, i can't find info on doing the same with it - taking dx11 output (in some form) and displaying it in MAUI control (or even directly rendering onto some control, if possible), so, my question is, is there a way to do it?

Comment: DirectX works only on Windows. With Maui, Windows platform is represented by WinUI3. WinUI3 can use a SwapChainPanel to interop with DirectX (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel). You have an example of WinUI3 + SwapChainPanel + DirectX in C# here https://github.com/smourier/DirectN/tree/master/DirectN/DirectN.WinUI3.MinimalD3D11

Comment: Oh, you are right, I’m dumb, for some reason I forgot directx itself is bound to windows